# How to read console input until space or enter in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I have just started learning C#. When it comes to reading input from the console I know there is `Console.ReadLine()` which reads input until the end of the line, but I am looking to read input until either the end of the line or a space, somewhat like `std::cin` in c++. The input `a b c` should be able to be read as:

```
a b c
```

or

```
a b
c
```

or

```
a
b c
```

or

```
a
b
c
```

and the result should be the same.

Comment: You could write your own function that loops a `Console.Read()` until your exit characters are found

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Console` class supports two read methods.

`Read()` will read a single character
`ReadLine()` will read all content to the end of the line (e.g. until an Environment.NewLine character.

It appears from your info above, that you simply want to read everything over multiple lines and then split it into tokens. You can do this by grabbing the standard input stream and reading it to "the end"... that is when a <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> is received.

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput(), Console.InputEncoding))
{
    var input = sr.ReadToEnd();

    var tokens = input.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ").Split(" ");

    foreach (var t in tokens)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Token: \"{t}\"");
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, that was what I was looking for.

Comment: Well give it a +1 and a check so :-)

Comment: I actually had less than 15 reputation, so the +1 didn't count,

Comment: Hah. No worries :-)